# Navbar content not hiding on resize

Tags: css

I have a "navbar" which hides when the width of the window is bigger than 730px

**

### NavBar

**

```
#topBar {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(233, 239, 249, 0.8);
    padding-top: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**

### On-resize

**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 730px) {
    #topBar {
            padding: 0;
            height: 0;
            }
}
```

The thing is that the content inside the div (#topBar) is not hiding with it, right now my solution was to use display:none on the dive which wraps the content of the Navbar, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution to this. Thanks!

**

### HTML

**

```
<div id="topBar">
    <div class="contentTopBar">
        <h1>{{actName}}</h1>
        <button class="Hecho" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveGame()">{{modalButton}}<img src="/modulos/icons/check.png" class="startIcon"></button>
        <button class="Tienda" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="goStore()">Ir a la Tienda<img src="/modulos/icons/Store.png" class="storeIcon"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**

### Content Navbar

**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 730px) {
   .contentTopBar{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: HTML added, as I say before right now my solution is to use display:none, but this looks "messy" when the Navbar is doing the transition of showing or hiding.

Comment: See my answer below. Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: That's it!! perfect! thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help.  If the solution works, can you accept it, so that others with the same problem can see how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding `visibility: hidden;` into your media query.  That will hide everything inside the navbar.

Here is a working example:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 730px) {
    #topBar {
            padding: 0;
            height: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            }
}

#topBar {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(233, 239, 249, 0.8);
    padding-top: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
    <div class="contentTopBar">
        <h1>{{actName}}</h1>
        <button class="Hecho" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveGame()">{{modalButton}}<img src="/modulos/icons/check.png" class="startIcon"></button>
        <button class="Tienda" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="goStore()">Ir a la Tienda<img src="/modulos/icons/Store.png" class="storeIcon"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```